# Driving into the US from Canada as a foreign worker

Tags: usa, borders

I live and work in Canada on a work permit (also recently applied for PR), and I hold a valid US visa (B1/B2).
I've visited the US a few times, and never had any issues.
In my previous visits however, I either flew in by myself, or drove with my Canadian partner.

I'd like to take a longer trip (3-5 weeks) to explore the outdoors more, but this time I'll be traveling solo, and I'd prefer to drive in with my own car, instead of flying.

I read somewhere (can't find the reference) that crossing the border overland is different/trickier than flying, especially for solo travelers, maybe because when flying one would normally have a return ticket.

Is there any basis for this claim? any particular gotchas and tips for crossing overland?
Would the answer be any different if I were to drive a camper van, or an SUV with some kind fix bed in the back?

Comment: I'm in a similar situation to you - foreign resident in Mexico with B1/B2 visa for the US.  I travel regularly into the US by land from Mexico (and have done a handful of times from Canada) on my B2 visa and no issues.  Make sure you have or obtain a valid I-94 when you cross (I believe you can do this via the "CBP One" phone app, although I don't know if this works for every port of entry), and ensure the I-94 remains current for your entire stay.